# Can you deploy a Gen2 cloud function from below the top level of a Cloud Source repository?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, gcloud

It appears that you cannot deploy a Gen2 cloud function using gcloud from a cloud source repo unless it is at the top level.

Here's a sample redacted deploy command for a gen 1 python function that works:

`gcloud beta functions deploy funcname --source https://source.developers.google.com/projects/projectname/repos/reponame/moveable-aliases/main/paths/pathname --runtime python310 --trigger-http --project=projectname`

if you add the -gen2 flag, it fails because it can't find main.py. Error is:

> OperationError: code=3, message=Build failed with status: FAILURE and message: missing main.py and GOOGLE_FUNCTION_SOURCE not specified. Either create the function in main.py or specify GOOGLE_FUNCTION_SOURCE to point to the file that contains the function.

If you add main.py to the root of the repo and run the same command, it finds main.py, which indicates to me that it isn't honoring the paths.

There is an additional problem which doesn't matter unless the first one is fixed, which is that if pathname is below the top level (folder/subfolder) gcloud sees that as a syntax error when the gen2 flag is set, but not without it.

Is there any way around this? It is very inconvenient.

Comment: I suspect this may be a problem with the gcloud version. I will update if that turns out to be true.

Comment: Nope, tried with the 2022.9.12 version of gcloud beta, still can't find main.py unless I move it to the root of the repo.

Comment: I suspect an unsupported feature because gen2 is still in preview. Open a case to the support to track the bug and have a fix in the future.

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/248110968

Answer (score 1):

Answering as community wiki.As per above comments

There is a  bug raised for this at [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/248110968). Which is still open further progress can be tracked there.

Comment: yeah still not solved ...